# Rule of Sum and Rule of Product

Tags: combinatorics

If adjacent regions should have different colors, how many ways can I have to color the regions with 4 different colors ? We do not need to use all four colors, yet each region is supposed to be colored by any of them.
I got the answer as  4!*4=96. But, I certainly feel that there are some same colors in neighboring regions and I have to minus it from the total number. I could not come up with any idea about finding same color in neighboring regions. I am trying to understand this concept. Could you please help me to understand this type of questions? Thanks in advance

[a square is divided into four regions and each region has a different size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZnzd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to break it up into cases, by considering the possible patterns of colors of colors.

First, you could color each region a different color.  There are $4!$ ways to do this.  Second, you could color the top and bottom the same color, and the left and right different colors.  Again there are $24$ ways to do this.  Also, you could color the left and right the same, and the op and bottome different, so that's another $24$.

Finally, you can color the top and bottom the same color, and and color both the left and right with a second color in $12$ ways.

That's all she wrote.  $84$ ways in total.

I guess the thing to realize is that each region is adjacent to exactly two others, so it can only be colored the same as one other region.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In the last step, is coloring left and right side with second color means that they are same colors? or will we color them differently? @saulspatz

Comment: @enes I mean color top and bottom red, and color left and right blue, for example.  The coloring where top and bottom are both red, left is blue, and right is green was already counted in one of the previous cases.